# Android v iOS user interface differences

Tags: flutter, user-interface, mobile-development

I have finished v1 of my mobile app (in Flutter). It has been designed for the Android os and now I need to make changes so when run on an iPhone, it'll look more like an iOS app. The first thing I'd like to do is replace the hamburger side slide in menu (the drawer menu).

I've always been an Android user, so I don't have much knowledge of how iPhone apps look. But i think their main menu is like a toolbar at the bottom of the screen?

The following is Flutter code I have in all my screens to create the top header panel and the drawer menu:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: rmoAppBar(subText: 'My Jobs'),
        drawer: RmoMenu(),
        body: isLoading
            ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
            : Column(
```

What should i do to make this more for iOS as far as the menu goes? And how? Thanks.